# OnExceptionAspect with Async/Await

Tags: postsharp

I want to use `OnExceptionAspect` from PostSharp. Want to know whether this aspect support Async methods or not?

Can anyone suggest links or sample code?

Thanks.

Comment: PostSharp 3 supports async for some calls. Though which type of async do you mean? There are several styles, .Net 2, .Net 4 style, .Net 4.5 async/await, etc. Have you looked at the API reference documentation to see if the method signature supports the type you want to use?

Answer (score 3):

To enable full compatibility of `OnExceptionAspect` with async methods, you need to set the [ApplyToStateMachine](http://doc.postsharp.net/p_postsharp_aspects_onmethodboundaryaspect_applytostatemachine) property to `true`, for example in your aspect's constructor.

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomAspect : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public CustomAspect()
    {
        ApplyToStateMachine = true;
    }
    // ...
}
```

There's more information about using `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` with async methods in [documentation](http://doc.postsharp.net/async-methods) and it is also applicable to `OnExceptionAspect`.

One important caveat is that you cannot change the exception's [flow behavior](http://doc.postsharp.net/p_postsharp_aspects_methodexecutionargs_flowbehavior) in async methods. So, you can't, for example, ignore the exception being thrown, while you still can do some logging or processing on it.

Comment: No, full support for state machines (async and iterators) is available only with the commercial license of PostSharp.